# Logcat empty using ACRA on device

Tags: android, logcat, acra

So I'm using ACRA 4.4.0 with all defaults, and my logcat field is empty.

My app has the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

permissions, which should at least give me [my own app logs](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-Adding_logcat,_eventlog_or_radiolog_extracts_to_reports) since [Jelly Bean](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/android-developers/READ_LOGS/android-developers/6U4A5irWang/8xOi74KfRIYJ).

> Final note: READ_LOG permission is not granted to third-party apps
>   anymore since Android 4.1 (JellyBean). Starting with this version,
>   logcat provides only traces **from your own app**, without requiring a
>   permission. JellyBean logcat logs are retrieved by ACRA starting with
>   version 4.3.0b2

So I do a forced log:

```
Log.i("mytag" , "message");
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(null);
```

On the emulator (v4.2), I get the full logcat. (Which BTW is somewhat contradictory to the JB imposed logcat restriction)
However, on my device v4.2.1, the logcat is completely empty.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Having the same problem, neither acra 4.2.3 nor 4.4.0 gives any output on my 4.2.1 devices. Even playing with the acra @ReportsCrashes params makes no difference. Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Did you able to get the Logcat on your device ? I am still not able to get it.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using email-mode acra reporting (`mailTo` tag inside `@ReportsCrashes`) the LogCat field isn't included to decrease the report size. To get around this you just need to use the customReportContent tag.

(Took a while of searching before I found this - it is written in the documentation, just not in the section mentioning LogCat)

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "",
    mailTo = "xxxx@yyyy.com",
    customReportContent = {ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)
```

Note: I excluded the USER_CONTENT and CUSTOM_DATA field

Note2: `import org.acra.ReportField;`

Comment: Thanks this helped me, I was able to email the logcat using ACRA-4.5.0 and running on android 4.1.2 targets (Jelly Bean).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is because starting with JellyBean you cannot use READ_LOGS anymore. For further explanation read here:

```
http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html
```

Comment: Well, ACRA author says otherwise regarding the owning app log

Comment: Can you provide some links? Maybe it is about providing to ACRA custom log files? I Doubt it would read logcat entries like crash dumps on 4.1+

Comment: If you are rooted/running from /system/app it can read logs apparently. If you're doing the root method you'd have to execute the application from a shell running as root. Which would be the responsibility of the app developer. (I am the developer of Log This)

Comment: The behavior documented in the ACRA wiki is based on this discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/6U4A5irWang/8ar5-9lLmaAJ - Dianne Hackborn: _The kernel drive does this based on whether you have the permission to access the full logs.  If not, it only gives you the logs associated with your uid._ As I don't have any JellyBeans device, I only tested it on SDK emulator.

Comment: @KevinGaudin, yeah, as far as I can tell I should be able to get my logs, but I don't. Again, on the emulator it works fine, but not on a device.