# ACRA logcat -t truncated

Tags: android, acra

The logcat, when requested through ACRA is not inluding most of the requested line. That is, if I request 1000 lines, I only get maybe 200.

For example, In @ReportCrashes, I'm using:

```
logcatArguments = { "-t", "1000", "-d", "-v", "time"},
```

This is a very similar question to 
[acra logcat missing lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926806/acra-logcat-missing-lines)

The difference is that I compared the exact same logcat command done through ACRA and done directly through adb. In the latter case, 1000 lines are returned.

Something appears to be happening in ACRA that is causing the loss of some of the log output. I can work around this (with quite a bit of additional work) by writing my own log file. It would be helpful if the bug could be fixed in ACRA or a simpler work around illuminated.

Comment: After more experimenting, it seems this may be a difference between the way Android handles logcat extractions versus adb. I've done several tests and doing a logcat extracting via ACRA versus my own code is returning the same results, indicating (as others have said) this is not an issue with ACRA. Still, I'm curious why the log doesn't contain all the lines it should.

Comment: I think android applies the line limit before the filter (there is an implicit filter, as you can only get logcat for your own app)